# iTunes lookup?bundleId method is not working for my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I'm trying to lookup my app from this method: http://itunes.apple.com/US/lookup?bundleId=com.writingfuture.where2

But it always return

```
{
 "resultCount":0,
 "results": []
}
```

---

My app status in the store is perfectly fine (ready for sale). Here's a detail:

- Bundle ID: com.writingfuture.where2
- Apple ID: 467311933
- Type: iOS App
- Version: 2.0.1
- Status:  Ready for Sale
- Date Created: Dec 4, 2012
- Date Released: Dec 10, 2012

---

I have no idea why I can't lookup for my app with this method.
Do you guys have any idea?

Thanks in advance,

Chammp

Comment: what is your app name and type ?

Comment: @MidhunMP My app name is Where2 and type is iOS App (iPhone free app).

Comment: I searched on the net but couldn't get your app

Comment: @MidhunMP https://itunes.apple.com/EN/app/where2/id467311933 Here's my app iTune store page.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Looks like your app is ONLY available in Thailand storefront - so the lookup should include country code in the base lookup URL:

- http://itunes.apple.com/th/lookup?bundleId=com.writingfuture.where2

The alternative to using bundleId is simply looking up by adamID:

- http://itunes.apple.com/th/lookup?id=467311933

Comment: It's exactly right. My app is only available in Thailand, but I was looking in US store. That's why it's not found. Thank you!

Comment: What if I have only the ID of resource without knowing any country limitations?

Comment: @GajusKuizinas If you don't know the country, you would have to just loop through every country code (155 in total).

Comment: @TedHosmann Thats what I am I afraid of. This dramatically increases the number of requests required to research a set of IDs. Its Okay if you have 10 IDs. It not Okay if you have tens of thousands (as I do).

Answer (score 1):

If your app is available only in Thailand you should add info about country in request

http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.writingfuture.where2&country=th

Answer (score -2):

**If the API response returns `"resultCount":0` and `"results":[]` it means that there is no app found with the specified bundle ID or the bundle ID is incorrect.**

Here are some possible solutions to this issue:

In my case region is issue my app support only India region so i did not get the results after adding \in\ in URI i got the results

Ensure that the **region/country** of the App Store that you are targeting is correct. You can check this in your app's settings on App Store Connect.

Comment: If this is ChatGPT output, you should delete it because all AI-generated content is banned on Stack Overflow, and because if you've plagiarized someone else's content, even an AI's, then you are in violation of the Code of Conduct you agreed to follow.