# ITunes lookup api doesn't work with language or country code?

Tags: app-store-connect, itunes

```
url = "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1510853708
```

This only returns English results. I want to add a language or country code for China, but none of these worked:

```
url = "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1510853708&country=cn
url = "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1510853708&l=zh
```

It returned 0 results. I changed id to bundleId, but is the same.

However, search api worked with country=cn. So why doesn't lookup api doesn't work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iTunes lookup?bundleId method is not working for my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640834/itunes-lookupbundleid-method-is-not-working-for-my-app)

Answer (score 0):

try this "https://itunes.apple.com/cn/lookup?id=",
and confirmed that your app sales areas contains China mainland.

Comment: Welcome to SOF, please comment one-line answers, thanks