# Why lookup by bundleId API does not return a result?

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes, bundle-identifier

Folks,

I have google and found many answers which really do not work for me about lookup API of apple.

I am trying to get version details for my app and calling the below API but it returns the following result every time.

http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.itouchvision.MCSUK

{
"resultCount":0,
"results": []
}

Note that: The app is on App Store and I tried with https://, country code, and even with id parameters but nothing returns a result.

Any idea, please let me know. Thank You!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iTunes lookup?bundleId method is not working for my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640834/itunes-lookupbundleid-method-is-not-working-for-my-app)

Comment: Yeah, it was issue with county for me. Fixed it already.